# Add all items from HashSet<T> to Map<String,T>

Tags: java, performance, collections

I have a `HashSet<T>` of objects that I want to insert into a `Map<String,T>` where the String key is a property of T. What is most efficient way to do this? I'm guessing there is a better way than what I have currently:

```
Map<String,T> myMap = new HashMap<String,T>();
HashSet<T> mySet = new LinkedHashSet<T>();

... Add some T's to mySet

for(T t : mySet){
    myMap.put(t.getObjectKey(), t);
}
```

Comment: You can use Guava to streamline it, but in the underlying code it'll be doing the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve that in Java 8 using [lambda expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) :

```
Map<String, T> myMap =  mySet.stream()
                             .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x.getObjectKey(),x -> x));
```

where T is the type of your objects and assuming that `x.getObjectKey()` returns a `String`.

Demo [**here**](http://www.tryjava8.com/app/snippets/529f8138e4b02df762a58f94).

Comment: Very elegant. But it doesn't seem like it would be more efficient than the for loop...essentially still O(n), right?

Comment: @Tom I did'nt explore the trees under the forest, but you will still iterate over all the elements of the stream. So yes, i would say that is still O(n).

Answer (score 1):

The Guava library allows you to use a more functional-style way to express roughly what you're doing, but it's not going to be more efficient, and with the current state of the Java programming language it won't be particularly pretty either.

Until we get lambda expressions in Java 8, you're pretty much stuck doing exactly what you've done.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to answer, bu i will make an answer: If i required to have options something like this, i would design a custom `HashMap` for myself following OOP tradition: allowing any type of `Collection` of type `Set` and `List`.

1. The Object class which are going to be mapped as (key, value) pair entry in `HashMap<K, V>` should have a function `getRelationalKey()` with return type `K`. Hence we need to mark the object class as a type Relational for forcing the implementation. We will use the help of an interface:

   ```
    interface Relational<T>
    {
         public T getRelationalKey();
    }
   ```
2. The `HashMap<K, V>` should have a function `putAllFromRCollection(Collection)` to put all such Object of the collection to the `Map`. Hence, the function declaration with signature should be something like: `putAllFromRCollection(Collection<? extends Relational<K>> collection`. Hence, the custom `HashMap`: `MyHashMap` can have an implementation like:

   ```
   class MyHashMap<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V>
   {

       public void putAllFromRCollection(Collection<? extends Relational<K>> collection)
       {
           for(Relational<K> relObj: collection)
           {
               put(relObj.getRelationalKey(), (V)relObj);
           }
      }

   }
   ```

It is time for a test case: Lets declare a class:

```
class ATestClass implements Relational<String>
{
    public String name;
    public String address;

    public ATestClass(String name, String address) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }


    @Override
    public String getRelationalKey() {
      return name;// or address or whatever should be regarded as a key 
    }

}
```

And add some object of this class to a `HashSet`:

```
HashSet<ATestClass>testSet = new HashSet<>();
testSet.add(new ATestClass("AName", "A-Adress"));
testSet.add(new ATestClass("BName", "B-Adress"));
testSet.add(new ATestClass("CName", "C-Adress"));
testSet.add(new ATestClass("DName", "D-Adress"));

MyHashMap<String, ATestClass>myMap = new MyHashMap<>();
myMap.putAllFromRCollection(testSet);

System.out.println(myMap);
```

**Output:**

```
{
 CName=CollectionsTest.ATestClass@c21495, 
 BName=CollectionsTest.ATestClass@14b7453, 
 DName=CollectionsTest.ATestClass@1d5550d, 
 AName=CollectionsTest.ATestClass@1186fab
}
```

The advantages are:

- we are now allowed to define required data type of the key to make the relation with the object
- set a specific target field of Class as the `Key` matching type of the `HashMap`'S key
- Allowing any type of `Collection<E>` instead of just a `HashSet`

In this implementation however, i have avoided to provide code for resizing the map with the size of the provided `Collection` for performance achievement. Please refer to the `putAll(Map)` function's source for details.

Comment: Nice answer...but I was asking for a more efficient method than the for loop. Your answer essentially has the same for loop that I'm already using.

Comment: Yes, but if i needed such implementation i would design the approach this way for future reuse and allowing maximum flexibility for all other collection. And As it is already answered that there is actually no way other than waiting for JAVA8 and(or) using extra library Guava. My personal opinion is even if lambda is available, i would still implement my approach. :) Thank you